# ¿Como insertar el rol de un usuario al registrarlo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, identityuser

Intento agregar el rol a un usuario en el momento de registrarlo pero no se como hacer q cuando le de crear el me guarde en la tabla *aspUserRole* que tiene por defecto *identity*.

Este es mi controlador:

```
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {

        ApplicationDbContext userContext;
        userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var roles = userContext.Roles.ToList();
        ViewBag.roles = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

               

               
                    //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // Para obtener más información sobre cómo habilitar la confirmación de cuenta y el restablecimiento de contraseña, visite http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Enviar correo electrónico con este vínculo
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmar cuenta", "Para confirmar la cuenta, haga clic <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aquí</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ApplicationUsers");
                //}
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // Si llegamos a este punto, es que se ha producido un error y volvemos a mostrar el formulario
        return View(model);
    }
```

Mi vista:

```
 @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
 @Html.DropDownList("roles",ViewBag.roles as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de crear el usuario puedes usar el método `AddToRoleAsync(TUser, String)`.
El cual te permite como su nombre lo indica agregar un Role al usuario.
Tendrías algo así:

```
 var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
 if (result.Succeeded)
 {
   UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, model.Rol);

 }
```